# Flutter-About the number of reads when creating a chat app in Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I create chap app now. 
In some of the tutorials, when you read chat messages, you write the following code.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('chat').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError)
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
      default:
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return Text(document["message"]);
          }).toList(),
        );
    }
  }
)
```

In the above implementation, I think that if the number of messages is large, the number of readings will increase dramatically.

If there are 100 messages in the database, every time a message is added it will be 100 or more reads, right?
Or does the FireStore SDK handle it well?

it is my question.

Please tell me the code that reduces the number of reads.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use a stream, the Firebase client keeps an active observer between the client and the server. For the first 30 minutes after starting this observer that means it'll only need to synchronize the delta, so whatever documents it doesn't have in its local cache yet.